# How can I remove junk from end of zip file when unzipping and piping to new file?

Tags: windows, linux, macos, unzip

When I take a .tsv file ouput by Excel on a Mac, zip it, send it to a linux machine, and unzip it using the unzip command, I get a bunch of junk on the end of the file. In the file, I have 19 rows of data. I use the default "Compress" function from the right click menu in finder. I upload the file through PHP. Here is the command I run (manually or automatically from the script) on the zip file:

```
unzip -aajp {zipfile} > {newfile}
```

When I open the {newfile} I see all of this on the end of the file:

```
^@^E^V^G^@^B^@^@Mac OS X        ^@^B^@^@^@  ^@^@^@2^@^@^@ ^@^@^@^B^@^@^@R^@^@^@^@TEXTXCEL^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

Is there anyway to get rid of the junk on the end of the file?

When I run:

```
unzip -aaj {zipfile}
```

It will unzip the file, converting it to text/plain without the junk just fine. But then within my PHP script, I need to be able to get the exact name/location of the file.

I am open to doing this either way. I just cannot seem to find the correct solution. That being said, it needs to work for a file coming from windows as well. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Here is what I ended up doing, but it still feels sloppy. I am still open to a better solution.

```
function decompress($filename) {
    // generate a temporary filename
    $tmpfile = '/tmp/'.mt_rand();

    // Here we actually decompress the $working_zip_file file
    $command = "unzip -aao $filename -d $tmpfile/ | egrep \"(inflating:|extracting:)\" | grep -v MACOS ";
    $unzip_output = exec($command, $dummy, $unzipstatus);

    // If things where unzipped properly
    if($unzipstatus[0] == 0) {
        $work_plain_file = preg_match('/\s*(inflating:|extracting:)(.*)$/', $unzip_output, $matches);
        $work_plain_file =  trim($matches[2]);
        $clean_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $work_plain_file);
        if($clean_name != $work_plain_file){
            exec("mv \"$work_plain_file\" $clean_name");
            $work_plain_file = $clean_name;
        }
        rename($work_plain_file, $new_file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unzip` is dumb when it comes to the resource fork. You must tell it to ignore anything it finds in `.DS_Store`.

Comment: You could try `-x`, but I'm not sure if that only matches the last path component. You may need to use another tool do extract the file.

Comment: I was able to get that to work for extracting the file like this: `unzip -aao {FILENAME} -x *MACOSX* -x *._*` and it excluded all superfluous files.